# Connecting to postgres database returns "role <user> does not exist", however user exists

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ssh

I have a Rails application with its own database server and a slave database server (readonly) hosted on AWS.

The Rails application manages to connect to the database fine, and I'm also able to connect to the slave database server using the "psql" command line interface.

For a script I'm writing, I want to use the "pg" gem directly but receives a "role "deploy" does not exist (PG::ConnectionBad)" error.

This is the code I'm using to connect to the db:

```
require 'pg'
require 'net/ssh'

def copy_user(id)
  db_password = prompt_db_password

  puts 'Connecting to slave db server...'
  server = <address> # db slave
  Net::SSH.start(server, 'deploy') do |ssh|
    puts 'Connecting to database...'

    ssh.open_channel do |ch|
      connection = connect_with_pg(db_password)
      result = connection.exec('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items')
      puts result[0]['count']
    end
  end
end

def connect_with_pg(db_password)
  PG.connect(host: 'localhost', user: 'deploy', password: db_password, dbname: 'my_db_name')
end
```

The user "deploy" does exist, and also when I ssh to the slave db server and run `psql -h localhost -U deploy my_db_name`, and enter the password everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are connecting to "localhost" in connect_with_pg

Answer (score 1):

Could you try a different syntax?

```
 PG.connect(:host=> 'localhost', :user => 'deploy', :password =>db_password, :dbname => 'my_db_name')
```

Also in SSH.start make user a variable. And use password.
I've found some weird bug reports connected to this.

```
 password = <password>
    user = "deploy"
    Net::SSH.start(server, user, :password => password) do |ssh|
```

Overall, code works for me. There are no errors.